# Did anyone offered a resolution to Hilbert's most important question?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, reference-request

In 1900, Hilbert identified what he said was the *most important* unresolved question in the mathematics of the time:

> But above all I wish to designate the following as the most important among the numerous questions which can be asked with regard to the axioms: To prove that they are not contradictory, that is, that a definite number of logical steps based upon them can never lead to contradictory results.
>
> — David Hilbert, Lecture delivered in 1900 before the International Congress of Mathematicians in Paris

Did anyone offered a resolution and is there a consensus on this among mathematicians?

Thank you for scholarly references.

Comment: [Hilbert's Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_program) ended with Gödel

Comment: This is not "the most important question in mathematics", it is only "most important among the numerous questions" about some system of axioms. Specifically, he was talking about arithmetic, and it is known as [Hilbert's second problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_second_problem):"In the 1930s, Kurt Gödel and Gerhard Gentzen proved results that cast new light on the problem. Some feel that Gödel's theorems give a negative solution to the problem, while others consider Gentzen's proof as a partial positive solution."

Comment: Wikipedia has the complete list of Hilbert's 1900 problems with their current status. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_problems)

Comment: @Rushi, on target. Addresses the OP's concerns, which is David Hilbert's pet peeve: *Is mathematics **consistent***? Gödel's Incompleteness theorems show that ...

Comment: @Rushi, Hilbert's Program did not "end with Goedel".  A certain interpretation of it may be said to have ended with Goedel; other interpretations are still alive and well, and generating much work in contemporary logic.

Comment: There are still relevant questions related to Hilbert's second question. What notion of proof should we use, what are the sufficient axioms for Arithmetic, what meta-theory should we be working in? Are we trying to produce a proof from Peano Arithmetic, that Peano Arithmetic is consistent, assuming standard meta-theory? Then by Godel the answer is that if Peano Arithmetic is consistent- it cannot prove its own consistency. Hilbert's formulated second question is a bit open to interpretation, which makes it hard to have a consensus on.

Comment: If we want to prove that Peano Arithmetic, is consistent , from the perspective that ZF is consistent, then we are in the domain of relative consistency proofs, which a relevant field of study in modern logic.